# Why is the order in which notify() is called in the following blocking queue example important?

Tags: java, multithreading

I wrote a simple Blocking Queue example for a Prod-Cons problem. The example below won't work; unless I swap the add/remove part of the enqueue/dequeue logic with notify on the waiting thread. I couldn't find any clear explanation of this behavior in any implementation of BlockingQueue. In the enqueue part, shouldn't it be correct to add the element and then notify? In this way I can guarantee that when Consumer thread runs, it shall have a element to consumer and won't return null. Please explain.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class BlockingQueueCustom<T> {

    private int size = 10;
    private Queue<T> queue = new LinkedList<T>();

    public BlockingQueueCustom(int s) {
        this.size = s;
    }

    public synchronized void enqueue(T element) throws InterruptedException {
        while (queue.size() == size) {
            wait();
        }
        queue.add(element); //Comment this part to make it work
        if (queue.size() == 0) {
            this.notifyAll();
        }
        //queue.add(element); Uncommenting this will make it work
    }

    public synchronized T dequeue() throws InterruptedException {
        while (queue.size() == 0) {
            this.wait();
        }
        T element = queue.remove(); //Comment this part to make it work
        if (queue.size() == size) {
            this.notifyAll();
        }
            return element; //Comment this part to make it work
        //return queue.remove(); Uncommenting this will make it work
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you only notify when `queue.size() == 0`? When would that ever be the case, anyway?

Comment: @user2357112 : Well, I was thinking consumer thread may run the dequeue part and remove the element. But since the BlockingQueueCustom object is synchronized, consumer thread won't run unless producer thread has left enqueue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In the enqueue part, shouldn't it be correct to add the element and then notify?

That part doesn't really matter, as you're in a synchronized method - the other threads won't get to run until you've left the `enqueue` method anyway. However, it *does* matter in terms of the test for `size()`. Look here:

```
if (queue.size() == 0)
```

How do you expect that to be true if you've just added an element? You could check for it being 1 instead, meaning that *before* you added the element it must have been 0. Or you could keep a separate variable:

```
boolean shouldNotify = queue.size() == 0;
queue.add(element);
if (shouldNotify) {
    this.notifyAll();
}
```